# Using Intents to play audio files

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to create a media player that only plays .mp3 files. I have the list created and showing on my app but I cant get it to play the song. I was advised to use an intent but I dont know how to do it.

Here is the code;

```
ListView list;
Cursor cursor;
int columnIndex;
int count;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
private Button dropbox;

public MainActivity()
{

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dropbox = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dropbox);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    dropbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.dropbox.com"));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    String[] displayMusic = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, displayMusic, null, null, null);

    //0 is the id for a mp3 file on the sd card
    //1 is the file name of the mp3 file on the sd card
    final ArrayList<String> listOfMp3s = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> listOfIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        if(cursor.getString(1).endsWith("mp3"))
        {
            listOfMp3s.add(cursor.getString(1));
            listOfIds.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
    }



    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listOfMp3s);
    list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            Intent songPageIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SongPage.class);
                            startActivity(songPageIntent);
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html Check the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
String name = "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/sh/t0in0j8jgsr9wft/abc.mp2";
Uri a = Uri.parse(name);

Intent viewMediaIntent = new Intent();   
viewMediaIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);   
viewMediaIntent.setDataAndType(a, "audio/*");           
viewMediaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(viewMediaIntent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName){
    //set up MediaPlayer    
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+fileName);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```